# How can I call a generic WebAPI action from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, generics, asp.net-web-api, reflection

How can I call a generic WebAPI action from JavaScript? and pass the `T` type.

C#:

```
public class ClassUtilitiesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string GetClassNamespace<T>()
    {
        return typeof(T).FullName;
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$.post('/api/ClassUtilities', {
    T: 'string',
    // ...
});
```

I need an action that returns something from input `T` type (ex. `typeof(T).FullName` or Create an instance and call a method). What should I do?

Comment: what do you mean by something?

Comment: @arash (ex. `typeof(T).FullName` or Create an instance and call a method)

Comment: consider using factory pattern

Comment: @arash please explain more..

Comment: @Mohamadshiralizadeh I think you never need to know the T!!! Because the conversion from json object to C# object is not type dependant. Your method dows not take any input??? What do you want to return?

Answer (score -1):

The JSON data of the POST request it's actually a string, meaning that you have to deserialize is as the object you want.

Try:

```
public class ClassUtilitiesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string GetClassNamespace(string data)
    {
        T t;
        try
        {
            t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(data);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e;
        }
        return t.FullName;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can ensure you that it is working, I am working with this method all the time. Maybe your problem is with the authorization of the JSON input, try to add the [AuthorizeJson] attribute above the function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/7314198/roi-neu I paste your code into visual studio. I have 2 errors. `The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found` and 
`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Exception' to 'string'`

Comment: Make a model file for this controller in the model folder and create inside a new class call T (or any better name you choose). The T class represent the JSON content of this request, for example:
if the JSON is: 
    data: {
        num1: 1,
        name: "AName"
    }
The class will be: 
public class T()
{
    public int num1 { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

Comment: I think your don't know any thing about generics in C#, do you?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx